# jQuery validate - TypeError undefined

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am following the default example from the jQuery validation page, and am coming across the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

on this line:

`$('form').validate().on('submit', function(e) {`

When I attempt to submit an empty form I can see the default messages being triggered as expected however, when I submit the form filled out nothing is sent.

Without the .validate() the form submits fine.

**What is causing this error and the completed form to not go through using .validate()?**

html

```
<form id="form1" action="#" method="post">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" minlength="2" name="name" required>

    <label>Class Id:</label>
    <input type="text" minlength="2" name="class" required>

    <p><button type="submit">Submit</button></p>
</form>

<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jquery

```
(function() {
$('form').validate().on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.post('create.php', $(this).serialize(), function() { 
        console.log('Submission entered');
        window.location = 'contact_form.html'; 
    });
})
})();
```

Comment: You really should study [the example on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).  You would never attach a `.submit()` to the `.validate()` method.  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code...

```
$('form').validate().on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.post( .... );
});
```

I have never seen anyone try to attach a jQuery `.submit()` to the `.validate()` method.

Simply use the plugin's built-in `submitHandler` for this...

```
$('form').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('create.php', $(form).serialize(), function() { 
            console.log('Submission entered');
            window.location = 'contact_form.html'; 
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('form').validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('valid form');
            /* // for demo
            $.post('create.php', $(form).serialize(), function () {
                console.log('Submission entered');
                window.location = 'contact_form.html';
            });
            */
            return false;
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="#" method="post">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" minlength="2" name="name" required>
    <label>Class Id:</label>
    <input type="text" minlength="2" name="class" required>
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form>
```